# Are the coordinates 0 0 always in a spawn chunk?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I create a new world, will the coordinates x=0 z=0 always be in a spawn chunk?

By spawn chunk, I mean the Wiki definition:

> "Spawn chunks normally consist of an area of 16×16 chunks in the world spawn point."

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki, spawnchunks are always centered on your **world spawn** which is almost never actually 0,0.

However, since your spawn is usually very close to 0,0 there is a good chance it MIGHT be a spawnchunk. But again it might not be.

To be sure, you can find your worldspawn by using a compass, and then counting 9 chunks in every direction to see.

Answer (score 0):

No, in my experience the spawn chunk will rarely be At X=0 Z=0. If you are trying to find your spawn chunk then you can break your bed, and then follow your compass. The compass will always point towards you bed or spawn if no bed is found.

Comment: By "a spawn chunk," I meant the 16x16 area around you when you first load a world. Question edited for clarification.

Comment: @ginkgo yes this is what I mean. Your question was clear from the start. The compass will point to your first spawn and that area will be a spawn chunk. Hope  this helps!